# ITextSharp: Specify HTML Classes or ID CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, itext

I am converting some HTML into a .pdf file using ITextSharp.

**Is it possible to set a classes css in ITextSharp or can I only set HTML elements CSS?**

For example: If I convert the following HTML

```
<p class="redBigText">test</p>
```

Can I create a ITextSharp StyleSheet object and specify the CSS for the class **redBigText**?

```
StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(".redBigText", "font-size", "50px");
styles.LoadTagStyle(".redBigText", "color", "#ff0000");
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(mainContents), styles);
```

Or can I only set CSS elements in ITextSharp?

```
StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle("P", "font-size", "50px");
styles.LoadTagStyle("P", "color", "#ff0000");
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(mainContents), styles);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can specifiy a CSS class name:

```
string Html = @"
<h1>h1</h1>
<p>Default paragraph</p>  
<p class='redBigText'>A paragraph with CSS class</p>  
";
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadStyle("redBigText", "size", "20pt");
styles.LoadStyle("redBigText", "color", "#ff0000");
```

It's [documented here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/StyleSheet.html).

Unfortunately you cannot specify `id` attributes. Also be aware that if you mix and match `LoadTagStyle()` and `LoadStyle()` calls, the `LoadTagStyle()` wins. For example:

```
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle("p", "size", "10pt");
styles.LoadTagStyle("p", "color", "#0000ff");     
styles.LoadStyle("redBigText", "size", "20pt");
styles.LoadStyle("redBigText", "color", "#ff0000");
```

Here, all paragraphs are blue and 10pt.

Comment: NICE!!! It really does work for `<P>` tags at least... I'm using `iTextSharp 5.4.2` right now.

Comment: how to set the html into the document?

Comment: It does not supporting whole css attributes i guess, i tried **text-indent** for example but it did not worked :(

Answer (score 2):

although it is old post but might some one can get help by following solution.

You have to convert the following line

```
<p class="redBigText">test</p>
```

to

```
<p style="font-size : 50px;color : #ff0000">test</p>
```

itextsharp will now apply inline style to your html, it will not recognized css classes, as they are referenced from external file.

You can use 
[This inline styles tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) to convert you css classes to inline style.

- Just copy the css from your classes to your html page.
- copy the html to inliner tool.

You will get the inlined css html page. 
~Happy Codding