# How to preserve CSS using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, itext

i have a header at the top of my front page like this: [image]

i use iTextSharp code to generate its PDF ... but the resulting PDF do not contain this Header with black  :  instead some CSS is written in place of header like this:

[image]

How can i possibly fix this issue??

Code:

```
 protected void BtnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: CSS isn't supported in `HTMLWorker`. You need XML Worker: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use inline css? Because HTML/CSS parser in iTextSharp is not complete. So it may not work as you want.

Also check out the `LoadTagStyle` property of StyleSheet in iTextSharp, see if it helps.

For more details about it, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616429/604232